# compile ng-bind-html inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a special template problem... I have a array of products, every products have a property "button_code", this property is a result in plain text of HTML laravel template with some angular code inside.

Actually im using a ng-bind-html="product.button_code" inside a  and use this template inside a ng-repeat, the html code is correctly inserted in every repeat iteration, but the code is plain text, and I need to "wake up" the ng-controllers ng-clicks etc inside this html

I try with this:

```
        var targets = $('.buy-button-container').toArray();
        for (var target in targets) {
        console.log($(targets[target]));
            $compile($(targets[target]))($scope);
        }
        $scope.$apply();
```

But this make the code inside the container (all html code inserted in the ng-bind-html) dissapear of the DOM.

How i can do this? 
PD: and yes, im forced to use these template in these product.button_code because special things...)

Thanks

EDIT: This is a piece of code i want to bind:

```
<button class="buy-link btn btn-default"  data-toggle="modal" role="button" ng-controller="BuyController" ng-click="doProduct({'id':'8888','title':'testestest','price':13.99,'currency':'EUR''preorder_enabled':false,'crossedPrice':100,'stock':true,'short_desc':'bla bla bla.','lbonus':false,'bonus_txt':false})">

                <span class="left">
                    <i class="fa fa-cart"></i>
                 <span itemprop="price">€13.99</span>
                </span>
                 <span class="right">
                  {{GETIT}}</span>
                </button>
```

Comment: Did you try the `ng-include` directive? If fetches and compiles external html.

Comment: Yes but the ng-include at least only work for me for angular templates or external html, but i need to use the product.button_code content, and i try to do ng-include="product.button_code" but dont works

Comment: Can you provide an example of the target and what you are trying to bind?

Comment: I edit the orifinal post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the transclude function furnished as the second argument of the function created by the `$compile` service:

```
app.directive("compileBindExpn", function($compile) {
    return function linkFn(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch("::"+attrs.compileBindExpn, function (html) {
             var expnLinker =  $compile(html);
             expnLinker(scope, function transclude(clone) {
                 elem.empty();
                 elem.append(clone);
             })
        });
    };
});
```

The above directive evaluates the `compile-bind-expn` attribute as an AngularJS expression. It then uses the `$compile` service to bind the evaluated HTML to the element. Any existing content will be removed.

Usage:

```
<div class="buy-button-container" compile-bind-expn="buttonCode">
    <p>This Node disappears when expression binds</p>
</div>
```

Note that the directive uses a one-time binding in the `$watch` to avoid memory leaks.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fx7smy6x/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to make HTML render you have to use the following function:

```
$sce.trustAsHtml('<b>Your html</b>');
```

You will have to inject $sce into your Controller.

If you are doing this in a ng-repeat you will need a function in your controller that does this. Ex:

```
$scope.transformHTML = function(html) {
  return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
}
```

in your template...

```
<div ng-repat="foo in bar">
  <div ng-bind-html="transformHTML(foo.html)"></div>
</div>
```

Anyway, I don't think that the "Angular" magic within your HTML will work.